# How to Write RestTemplate for accessing Webservice (GET , POST)

Tags: web-services, spring, webservice-client, resttemplate, webservicetemplate

**I am unable to form the request parameter for consuming REST web service GET and POST, could any one please guide based on below scenario.**

If I have REST webservice as below which is expecting two string parameters

***General Web URL to consume webservice :***

/myWs/sayHello?name=Peter&msg=Hai

//How to pass the arguments for getting GET and POST result.

```
 org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
 String url = "http://localhost:8080/myWs/sayHello";
 Map<String, String> vars = new HashMap<String, String>();
 vars.put("name", "peter");
 vars.put("msg", "Hai");
 String result = restTemplate.getForObject(url+"/{name}/{msg}", String.class, vars);
 String result1 = restTemplate.postForObject(url,  vars,String.class);

 System.out.println("GET result : "+result + "\nPOST result1"+result1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i normally perform a get:

a. RestTemplate request

```
// Create a new RestTemplate instance
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

// Add the Jackson message converter
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());

// Parameters
StringBuilder params = new StringBuilder();
params.append("?lat=");
params.append(lat);
params.append("&lng=");
params.append(lng);

// Make the HTTP GET request, marshaling the response from JSON to an array of Stations
Object results = restTemplate.getForObject(URL + params.toString(), ServiceStationJsonModel.class); 

// Do Something with the result
```

b. Web Service

```
@RequestMapping(value=URL, method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody Object nearmeServiceStationRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {

    String lat = request.getParameter("lat");
    String lng = request.getParameter("lng");
    // Do something with params
    ...
    return obj;
}
```

You can also use the **@PathVariable** annotations to get the parameters. An example of that as well of example on how to perform a post can be found [here](http://johnathanmarksmith.com/spring/java/javaconfig/programming/spring%20java%20configuration/spring%20mvc/web/rest/spring%20test%20framework/2013/06/12/how-to-make-a-web-service-with-spring-mvc-and-test-with-spring-test-framework/)

Hope this helps.